# Segmentation Fault in x86 Assembly Program

Tags: assembly, x86

I have made an assembly program to compute fibonacci numbers. It has many issues, but the most pressing right now is that when I try to use the predefined inputs (1, 2, 3) it segfaults after printing the correct predefined value. This is my first time trying jumps like this, and I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Any help would be much appreciated! I am writing on Linux Mint, and this code is for IA32 only. Also, asm_io is from a tutorial that I am using.

```
; This(fibonacci):
; it(computes the kth fibonacci number)

; Set up io
%include "asm_io.inc"

; This puts initialized data into the .data segment
segment .data
; Let's get some data:
prompt1 db "Enter kth fibonacci you want to see: ", 0

outmsg1 db "The ", 0
outmsg2 db "th fibonacci number is: ", 0

f0: dd 0x1
f1: dd 0x2
f2: dd 0x2
f3: dd 0x3

; We will put uninitialized stuff in .bss
segment .bss

; Store the input
input1 resd 1


; Code gets put into .text
segment .text
    global asm_main
asm_main:
    ; i need to learn what these do
    enter 0,0
    ; it turns out this puts everything into the stack
    ; that exists before we begin
    pusha

    mov eax, prompt1
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [input1], eax


start:
    mov ecx, [input1]
    mov edx, [f0]
    mov ebx, [f1]
    mov eax, [f2]
    push eax
    mov eax, 0x1
    cmp ecx, eax
    je inputisone
    mov eax, 0x2
    cmp ecx, eax
    je inputistwo
    mov eax, 0x3
    cmp ecx, eax
    je inputisthree
    pop eax

fibloop:
    add ebx, edx
    mov edx, eax
    mov eax, ebx

    dec ecx
    cmp ecx, 3
    jne fibloop
quit:
    push eax
    jmp finish


inputisone:
    mov eax, [f0]
    push eax
    jmp finish

inputistwo:
    mov eax, [f0]
    push eax
    jmp finish

inputisthree:
    mov eax, [f2]
    push eax
    jmp finish


finish:
    ; Register dump
    dump_regs 1            ; Print register values
    dump_mem 2, outmsg1, 1 ; Print memory
    ; Now we can print the results.
    mov eax, outmsg1
    call print_string
    mov eax, [input1]
    call print_int
    mov eax, outmsg2
    call print_string
    pop eax
    call print_int
    call print_nl

    ; this returns everything from the stack that we placed there
    ; for safekeeping before we ran our program
    popa
    mov eax, 0
    leave
    ret               ; back to C!
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What instruction segfaults?  How are you assembling+linking this?  What is the point of all that massively over-complicated branching, which looks like it just ends up setting eax = ecx, which you could have done with one `mov eax,ecx` and no constants from memory.  Or is it doing `eax = ecx-1`?  Also easy...  Oh, are you trying to skip the loop for small inputs?  `cmp ecx, 3` / `jbe`, instead of checking for equality with 3 different things.  You could use a lookup table of the first 4 Fib(n).  (Hint, they're not 1,2,2,3).

Comment: @PeterCordes I honestly don't know. This is my 5th assembly program ever! I really appreciate the advice -- I will work on the branching. I think the segfaulting instruction is popa at the end, but I'm not sure why. I am assembling and linking with nasm. I am using gcc as my compiler. Oh! Also, it does print out 1 1 2 3 as desired.

Comment: Don't guess, run your program under a debugger (like GDB) and see where it stops!  Trying to write asm without a debugger is like building a robot with your eyes closed.  Sure it's possible, but if you made any mistakes you will have a *hard* time finding them without being able to single-step and examine register values.

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay -- I will get a debugger and try it out!